# Trigonometric Functions: Argument reduction

Tags: python, math, precision, trigonometry, interval-arithmetic

I'm trying to implement trigonometric functions for interval arithmetic, preferably with `< ulp` error which requires precisely compute trigonometric functions manually. The first step is usually argument reduction, but I'm not really sure how argument reduction is usually implemented. For example, with [Python](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRCE3sSSDi6ugKDOvRAPE1ivOzNMwTDU0MNDUxCqsoKqgYaSgBdaoV5CpiakMzChKzU3MzEtJLYLo0lFA1fP/PwA), I get the following results:

```py
>>> import math
>>> math.sin(1e100)
-0.3806377310050287
```

What I expected it to do is apply modulo `2 * math.pi`, but this gives me a different result:

```py
>>> math.sin(1e100 % (2 * math.pi))
0.6806339877607344
>>> math.sin(math.remainder(1e100, 2 * math.pi))
0.6806339877607344
```

How is argument reduction done for trigonometric functions?

Comment: The problem is that 1e100 cannot be represented exactly in ieee 754 binary64 floating point, and `math.pi` is nowhere near 100 decimals in precision. So 1e100 % (2 * math.pi) is entirely inaccurate. What's amazing is that `math.sin(1e100)` somehow gets the correct answer of -0.3806377310050287, and I don't really understand how that's possible.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Yeah, I'm rather flabbergasted but also curious as to how it got there.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be the case that [most implementations](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/branred.c) simply use [high precision](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/895ef79e04a953cac1493863bcae29ad85657ee1/sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/branred.h#L61) with `pi`. There exists other strategies, but they all boil down to using lots of precision somehow. Once you have a highly precise value of `pi`, you can simply take `x % (2 * pi)` and work off of that.